# Convert fluid table to div / css

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I convert this 3-column table using divs only? Note the first and third columns are fluid and only the second (middle) column is fixed width.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#CCC;">left</td>
    <td style="width:940px; background-color:#0CF;">middle</td>
    <td style="background-color:#FF9;">right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to accomplish the DIV-based layout you desire: 
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Essentially, make the container DIV be 100% width, then position 3 "column" DIVs within it.

Comment: I went through the tutorial but it didn't explain what I needed :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

This problem of yours isn't as straightforward as you'd think it should be. It is straightforward to set 3 divs side by side and have the width of it all behave the way you want it to. Getting the height of all 3 of these divs to behave the way you want is a little more tricky.

This article, while not a tutorial specifically for your problem, may give you some good insights and ideas: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/

**Edit:**
A more specific article for your question: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/

Comment: I think I'll just go back to using tables. They're intuitive and work they way I want them to even though they're not supposed to be used for layouts. Thanks.